# Windows Store app button respond to click but event is not fired successfully

Tags: windows-store-apps

I go this response in Certification report:

> The app does not appear to fully support touch input. The various
>   tiles on the main screen respond to touch/clicks but do not launch an
>   action. Touch support in this app do not appear to work to our
>   reviewers. Please see:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh761498.aspx for
>   some of the common interactions for keyboard, mouse and touch.

This has never been an issue while developing and testing on several desktop computers and Surface RT. Any ideas on what might be the cause, or how I might reproduce it? The actions mentioned are hooked up to event handlers in code behind and use the navigation model with view models as parameters. I can post an example if needed, but there is nothing special in that code. What could cause a event-bound button to appear to be pressed but not call the handler, on some environments?

Extracts from one of the main features that the testers mention as non-functional:

View:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"..
```

Code behind:

> void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
>           {
>               var foodItem = (FoodItemViewModel)e.ClickedItem;
>               var mainViewModel = (MainViewModel)this.DefaultViewModel["MainViewModel"];
>               mainViewModel.CurrentItem = foodItem;
>
> ```
>         this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemDetailPageReadOnly), (MainViewModel)mainViewModel);
>     }
> ```

From ItemDetailPageReadOnly:

> protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter,
>   Dictionary pageState)
>           {
>               if (pageState != null && pageState.ContainsKey("SelectedItem"))
>               {
>                   navigationParameter = pageState["SelectedItem"];
>               }
>
> ```
>         var mainVm = (MainViewModel)navigationParameter;
>         this.DefaultViewModel["MainViewModel"] = mainVm;
>         this.DefaultViewModel["Item"] = mainVm.CurrentItem;
>     }
> ```

I would expect a NullPointerException if any of the parameters were null, not the described behavior from the testers.

Comment: Bugs in the platform for once. You could try resubmitting. Have you checked with touch though? You can also do that in the simulator.

Comment: It seems to me that this has been the reason for all the 8 submission rejections so I think this behavior is consequent on the testers part. I would appreciate any tips on relevant issues other developers have encountered. My next attempt will be to replace the event handlers in code-behind with command bindings, and figure out a way to implement page navigation here. I will also inspect the generated template code for the LayoutAware base class.

Comment: You can try sharing some of your code. Perhaps you missed something in the description.

Answer (score 0):

you should use one of the higher level events unless you need to respond to a specific portion of the gesture. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh994936.aspx